# Converting 16-digit hexadecimal string into double value in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I want to convert 16-digit hexadecimal numbers into doubles. I actually did the reverse of this before which worked fine:

```
import struct
import wrap

def double_to_hex(doublein):
            return hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', doublein))[0])

for i in modified_list:
        encoded_list.append(double_to_hex(i))
modified_list.clear()

encoded_msg = ''.join(encoded_list).replace('0x', '')
encoded_list.clear()
print_command('encode', encoded_message)
```

And now I want to sort of do the reverse. I tried this without success:

```
from textwrap import wrap
import struct
import binascii

MESSAGE = 'c030a85d52ae57eac0129263c4fffc34'

#Splitting up message into n 16-bit strings
MSGLIST = wrap(MESSAGE, 16)
doubles = []
print(MSGLIST)

for msg in MSGLIST:
    doubles.append(struct.unpack('d', binascii.unhexlify(msg)))
print(doubles)
```

However, when I run this, I get crazy values, which are of course not what I put in:
`[(-1.8561629252326087e+204,), (1.8922789420412524e-53,)]`

Answer (score 1):

Were your original numbers -16.657673995556173 and -4.642958715557189 ?

If so, then the problem is that your hex strings contain the big-endian (most-significant byte first) representation of the double, but the `'d'` format string in your `unpack` call specifies conversion using your system's native format, which happens to be little-endian (least-significant byte first).  The result is that `unpack` reads and processes the bytes of the `unhexlify`'ed string from the wrong end. Unsurprisingly, that will produce the wrong value.

To fix, do one of:

- convert the hex string into little-endian format (reverse the bytes, so `c030a85d52ae57ea` becomes `ea57ae525da830c0`) before passing it to `binascii.unhexlify`, or
- reverse the bytes produced by `unhexlify` (change `binascii.unhexlify(msg)` to `binascii.unhexlify(msg)[::-1]`) before you pass them to `unpack`, or
- tell `unpack` to do the conversion using big-endian order (replace the format string `'d'` with `'>d'`)

I'd go with the last one, replacing the format string.

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed response, however I have now found a much simpler solution to my problem. I simply encoded the beginning `int` using `hex()` and then decoded it with `int(hex_number, 16)`.